# Convergence in probability to inverse of singular matrix

Tags: probability-theory

We have two sequences of square and symmetric random matrices $\mathbf{A}_n$ and $\mathbf{B}_n$ where $\mathbf{A}_n$ is positive definite $\forall n$ and $plim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{A}_n = \mathbf{0}$. $\mathbf{B}_n$ is positive semi-definite and singular $\forall n$ and also converges in probability to singular $\mathbf{B} \neq \mathbf{0}$. Can we show that

$$plim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\mathbf{A}_n + \mathbf{B}_n)^{-1}\mathbf{B}_n = \mathbf{I},$$

where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix? Continuous mapping theorem will be difficult to apply since it will result in $\mathbf{B}^{-1}\mathbf{B}$.

Comment: Do you have a reason to suspect this to be true? Considering 1-by-1 matrices $A_n=1/n$ as well as $B_n=1/n$ seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Or just take $B_n$ as the all-zero matrix. Note: Perhaps you intended the matrices to be “non singular” (invertible).

Comment: @SmallDeviation Why is $1/n$ singular? Let us take $\mathbf{B}_n$ being the all zero matrix out as an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true. Consider the sequence of matrices $$A_n=\begin{pmatrix}
1/n & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 1/n & 0 &\dots & 0 \\
\dots &\dots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1/n \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$B_n=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & \dots & \dots &0  \\
0  & 1/n & 0 &\dots & 0 \\
\dots & \dots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots &0 \end{pmatrix}$$ Then $$(A_n+B_n)^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1+1/n & 0 & \dots & \dots &0  \\
0  & 2/n & 0 &\dots & 0 \\
\dots & \dots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots &1/n\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 n/(n+1) & 0 & \dots & \dots &0  \\
0  & n/2 & 0 &\dots & 0 \\
\dots & \dots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots &n \end{pmatrix}$$ and therefore
$$(A_n+B_n)^{-1}\cdot B_n = \begin{pmatrix} n/(n+1) & 0 & \dots & \dots &0  \\
0  & 1/2 & 0 &\dots & 0 \\
\dots & \dots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots &0 \end{pmatrix}$$ which certainly does not converge to $\textbf{I}$.

Note also that if $B_n$ is singular then $(A_n+B_n)^{-1}\cdot B_n$ is singular as well, therefore there's no reason to expect it to converge to $\textbf{I}$, which is non-singular, in general.